# How can we read broadcasted message from unsecured iBeacon?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

Is it possible to read iBeacon broadcasting message, that is unsecured without knowing the identifier to connect or monitor them? Basically in iOS you need to specify the UDID of that iBeacon in order to monitor it rather then we need the list of all the beacons that are near by and fetch its broadcasting message like location etc..

Comment: In iOS you can't listen to "unknown UUID Beacons", while on Mac OSX, Windows, Android, you can.

Comment: This is true, except for Windows which cannot scans for BLE beacons at all as of Windrows 8.1.

Comment: @Larme you are correct had find this good article suggesting the same http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html

Answer (score 0):

On iOS you cannot see iBeacons for which you have not provided the ProximityUUID up front.  This is a limitation of the iOS APIs and the operating system.

You can specify up to 20 ProximityUUIDs simultaneously for monitoring (and more for ranging).  You can even rotate more UUIDs into your list over time.  This would allow you to use a list of known UUIDs from a source like wikibeacon.org to find many beacons nearby.  But it will not let you see any beacon with an unpublished and unknown UUID.

For this, you can use a beacon scanner app on Android, OSX or Linux which have no such restrictions.